# how can i find blazor text editor with image upload example

Tags: blazor

I'm looking for an easy-to-use text editor in BLAZOR on day 3.
However, most of the examples do not provide an image file upload.

I found two easy ways below, but it's still difficult for me.

1. https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor
2. https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/rich-text-editor/how-to/rename-image/

I tried Blazored.TextEditor... But it doesn't include an example that simply uploads

can you help me a little bit..?
Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 1):

I am answering the File Upload portion of the question. I do not personally think a Text Editor and File Upload are related components, other than in the user interface you are building.

You can use an input type=text to edit. Are you wanting to display image data inside your textbox, like a Stackover flow post like this?

[image]

I am a little confused on your use case, but in my sample project Blazor Image Gallery, I upload profile pictures in my sign up component, but they are not display in a text editor, just in the component markup.

I have an open source project called and Nuget package called Blazor File Upload.

Source Code including Sample Project
https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorFileUpload

Nuget Package:
DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload

Another more advanced blog / sample project / tutorial / video

Building Blazor Image Gallery

https://datajugglerblazor.blogspot.com/2020/02/building-blazor-image-gallery-complete.html

Blazor Image Gallery Source Code
https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorImageGallery

Video: Building Blazor Image Gallery
https://youtu.be/3xKXJQ4qThQ

(Stackoverflow)
This is 100% directly answering the question asked, so please do not consider my free code that I give away as spam.

Comment: I'm sorry I rippled late. Thanks for the reply.
But I decided not to use blazor. It's hard for me yet.
I'm going to create a page with a basic mvc net core.

Comment: It is funny, I have used MVC for 4 or 5 years now, and MVC seems complicated to me, but to each their own. I admit Blazor is new, I think that adds to the excitement to me.